# App isn't responding because of Service START_CONTINUATION_MASK

Tags: java, android

I use a `Service` class with several timers and want this service to continue, even if the user kills the app. I tried `START_STICKY` but after killing the app the timer restarts (because i start them in the `onStartCommand`).

Then i tried `START_CONTINUATION_MASK` and it worked pretty good, but sometimes after a while the app crashes with the error: "The app isn't responding. Do you want to close it?". I cannot use `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` or sth. else, because on each `onStartCommand` another timer is created with a duration, not a fixed end-time.

Is there a fix to solve this problem?

**edit**: this is my `onStartCommand`

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer(7000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                Log.d("ms till finish:", "" + millisUntilFinished);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                timerList.remove(this);
                Log.e("amount timers:", "" + timerList.size());

                if (timerList.size() == 0) {
                    stopSelf();
                }
            }
        };
        cdt.start();

        timerList.add(cdt);
        return START_CONTINUATION_MASK;
}
```

Comment: Any `onStartCommand()` code to show? I think `START_CONTINUATION_MASK` depends on it.

Comment: I added it into my question

Comment: Hey. Did you solve this? Im using START_CONTINUATION_MASK too; did you find out why the app crashes? Mine doesnt so far, but I'd like to know your reason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Then i tried START_CONTINUATION_MASK and it worked pretty good

Since that is not a valid return value, your results will vary by device and Android OS version. `START_CONTINUATION_MASK` is a bitmask, as the name suggests, showing which bits are used for the continuation rules for services. The only valid values for a return value from `onStartCommand()` are `START_STICKY`, `START_NOT_STICKY`, `START_REDELIVER_INTENT`, or `START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY`.

> want this service to continue, even if the user kills the app

The user and the OS are welcome to stop your service whenever the user and the OS want to, whether you like it or not.

> I tried START_STICKY but after killing the app the timer restarts (because i start them in the onStartCommand).

Store the details of the timers in some persistent data store (file, database, `SharedPreferences`), such that you can start up the timers again as needed when your process, and its service, are restarted.

Answer (score 0):

To keep a service running in the background even if the user kills the app or removes it from the recent apps, one should use a foreground service.