# background service for multitask downloader stops when close app from "recent apps"

Tags: android, service, background-process, android-download-manager, background-service

I have a downloader app project and I'm using a Service class for managing download tasks and showing notifications like this :
[image]
the problem: when I close app from recent apps by swiping , the Service will be stop. I cant use `startForeground` for notifications , because I have multiple notifications in one service . and I like `notify.setAutoCancel(true)` works fine.
here is AndroidManifest.xml code :

```
<service android:name=".Downloader"  android:exported="false" android:enabled="true"
android:stopWithTask="false" />
```

here is starting service :

```
public static void intentDownload(Context context , FileInfo info) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Downloader.class);
    intent.setAction(ACTION_DOWNLOAD);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TAG, info.Tag);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_APP_INFO, info);
    context.startService(intent);
}
```

and here is `onStartCommand` :

```
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (intent != null) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        FileInfo fInfo;
        String tag = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_TAG);
        switch (action) {
            case ACTION_DOWNLOAD:
                fInfo = (FileInfo) intent.getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_APP_INFO);
                download(fInfo);
                break;
            case ACTION_PAUSE:
                fInfo = (FileInfo) intent.getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_APP_INFO);
                pause(fInfo);
                break;
            case ACTION_CANCEL:
                cancel(tag);
                break;
            case ACTION_PAUSE_ALL:
                pauseAll();
                break;
            case ACTION_CANCEL_ALL:
                cancelAll();
                break;
        }
    } 
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

how can I fix it ?!

Comment: You can start the service again `onTaskRemoved`.

Comment: @SripadRaj , if I do this , I will lose tasks of downloads. service is running and working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are returning `START_STICKY` this service will stop whenever you close/kill the app because after the App closed all the Reference/Value will become `null` for all Intent as well as variables and so `STICKY` service will not able to get Intent value.

To continue service after app kills use `return START_REDELIVER_INTENT`

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}
```

See same problem [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39344155/sticky-service-not-restarting-when-created-in-custom-object/39344385#39344385)

Comment: tnx , I think `START_CONTINUATION_MASK` is better.

Comment: you did like to read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31186478/app-isnt-responding-because-of-service-start-continuation-mask

Comment: Yes you right , When i use START_REDELIVER_INTENT , i lose tasks and source , the service restarts again , are there any way for fix it without restarting .  tnx bro

Comment: Using foreground service!